# Windows Phone - Restricrt users from using previous version of an app

Tags: windows-phone, version, windows-phone-store

I am working on a Windows Phone News Client and recently we changed some of the APIs. For that some of the older versions of my app is crashing heavily as there are format mismatches.

My question: Is there any way available to restrict users of previous version (suppose version 1.0.0.0) using that particular version? Or, force them to download the latest version of app (suppose version 1.0.0.1) from store? Does Windows Phone Store have any built in feature for this purpose?

Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no such feature in Windows Phone Store to accomplish your requirement. When update available user will be notified, but the update won't get installed automatically without user action.

You should implement logic to restrict user in the application it self. For example, upon application start up, check current version against latest version in server, then close the application if it isn't up-to-date.

Comment: Then I'm guessing there is no way now to minimize this crash problems as I didn't check app version of client in previous release, have to wait till user updates to latest version. @har07

Comment: unfortunately, yes I think so.

Comment: yes, there isn't anyway to minimize the crashing problems. i still see tons of crash log from user using app that is 3 versions older